# Placing an order returns MYSQL Duplicate Entry!

Tags: magento2

The error is as follows:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '000000000-3' for key 'SALES_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID_STORE_ID', query was:
>   INSERT INTO `sales_order` (`state`, `status`, `protect_code`,
>   `shipping_description`, `is_virtual`, `store_id`, `customer_id`,
>   `base_discount_amount`, `base_grand_total`, `base_shipping_amount`,
>   `base_shipping_tax_amount`, `base_subtotal`, `base_tax_amount`,
>   `base_to_global_rate`, `base_to_order_rate`, `discount_amount`,
>   `grand_total`, `shipping_amount`, `shipping_tax_amount`,
>   `store_to_base_rate`, `store_to_order_rate`, `subtotal`, `tax_amount`,
>   `total_qty_ordered`, `customer_is_guest`, `customer_note_notify`,
>   `customer_group_id`, `quote_id`, `base_shipping_discount_amount`,
>   `base_subtotal_incl_tax`, `base_total_due`,
>   `shipping_discount_amount`, `subtotal_incl_tax`, `total_due`,
>   `weight`, `increment_id`, `applied_rule_ids`, `base_currency_code`,
>   `customer_email`, `customer_firstname`, `customer_lastname`,
>   `customer_middlename`, `discount_description`, `global_currency_code`,
>   `order_currency_code`, `remote_ip`, `shipping_method`,
>   `store_currency_code`, `store_name`, `x_forwarded_for`,
>   `total_item_count`, `customer_gender`,
>   `discount_tax_compensation_amount`,
>   `base_discount_tax_compensation_amount`,
>   `shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amount`, `shipping_incl_tax`,
>   `base_shipping_incl_tax`, `gift_message_id`, `base_credit_amount`,
>   `credit_amount`, `msp_cod_amount`, `base_msp_cod_amount`,
>   `msp_cod_tax_amount`, `base_msp_cod_tax_amount`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Have made the required entries in the `sales_sequence_meta` and `sales_sequence_profile` tables aswell.

Comment: what have you done in `sales_sequence_meta` and `sales_sequence_profile`

Comment: Made the entries for the corresponding store

Comment: Please share those entries or query

Comment: meta_id | entity_type | store_id | sequence_table
1 | order | 3 | sequence_order_3

Comment: do you have `sequence_order_3` table?

Comment: Yes I  have created it